# My bash script will not somehow properly exit after finish a tail loop

Tags: bash, shell

I've create a bash script to keep reading a log file and if it find a matches, it will break the loop and exit. I use `tail -f | while read lines ; do ... done` simple methods.

The first time I run the script, it reads and monitors the log as expected. On a different session / windows, I do a sudo password as this is the log I am searching for a successful root password changed. And once if it found a string I need it. Script will break the loop and exit 0

It is working on the first time it run. And I did ensure to check `ps` after exiting, there are no left over processes running in the background. Now the ISSUE is when I run it second time, it will somehow not think it is close or something, because it just runs the entire script including while loop and everything. How can I tell script run the entire thing, because in my while loop before it break, it will print found it before it break. And after breaking the loop , just before it exit 0, it will print exit script on screen. So when I run the second time, it print those two lines really fast. If I run again third time, same behavior it will super quickly run and exit script and print those two lines. And only if you run the forth time , then it will start the it properly. How I know if script start properly, well because when it start properly, on the console, it will hang there and that is because of `while` loop combined with `tail -f`. And once it found it, it will print those two line and then exit

I even tried `(journalctl -f &) | while read lines; do .... done`.
It is performing the same.

I have tried including some kill command in my script to kill the `tail -f` or `journalctl -f` process. And it seems like it works kind of. Instead of three time, it will only require two times. But I can not understand what is doing or why.

Below is my script

```
#!/bin/bash

tail -f  /var/log/auth.log | while read lines; do
        if [[ $lines =~ "password changed for root" ]] 
        then
                echo "found"
                break
                #pkill -9 -P $$ tail
        fi 
done 
echo "exit " 
#kill $(jobs -p)
exit 0
```

Comment: by default `tail -f` will show the last 10 lines of the file; my guess is the `password changed for root` message is (still) in those last 10 lines and so everytime you run your script you process this string again and agains and again ... until enough new lines have been added to the file so that the `password changed for root` string no longer shows up in the last 10 lines; you can confirm this by adding 10 new lines to the file and then running your script again ... or try `tail -n0 -f`

Comment: the comment about the script working the 4th time you run it is likely just due to the fact that enough lines have been added to the file such that the line containing the string `password changed for root` no longer shows up in the last 10 lines of the file

Comment: Hi @markp-fuso , OMG - thank you so much. You have made my day. This does now work properly.

Comment: @markp-fuso 
 So now it also explains why my daemon configuration, which calls this script, was acting up. Because my daemon is set to restart upon exit 0, when it exists, it will restart the script. But since this script was trying to look the entire 10 lines by default and it already found a match, in that case, it just echoes duplicate. And daemon will attempt to restart the script again until there are enough lines to push up above 10 lines, and then it will start properly.

Comment: So now I have implemented it and tested both scripts themselves and by my daemon. And it is working fine. Once again thanks for the help.

Comment: @markp-fuso sorry . so one more question. I have tried using tail -n1 -f as well and it seems to be doing the same in terns of result. A little confused what is the differences

Comment: `tail -n0 -f` will display no lines *currently* in the file; `tail -n1 -f` will show the last line *currently* in the file; if the last line contains the string `password changed for root` then `tail -n1 -f` is going to cause the same issues you originally described, ie, you'll process `password chnaged for root` a 2nd time

Comment: @markp-fuso So n0 -f will mean it does not print any line , then how is it printing every last new line or append to a file. So I have add in while loop, echo "$lines" >> /tmp/test.log

Comment: I am really confuse, because -n0 -f means tail will not print any line but yet still follow the log. Then why the two -n0 or -n1 both able to properly print out new lines and append to a tmp location

Comment: without a `-n` flag the tail will start by first displaying the last 10 lines *currently* in the file; with `-n1` tail with start by displaying the last line *currently* in the file; with `-n0` tail will not display any lines *currently* in the file; in all calls tail will display any *new* lines added to the file

Comment: Ok so can I understand it as.. if the code is display  tail -n1 -f pipe to while read lines do .... My code ... Done

Comment: That will allow my script to keep monitor the source log of it's last line and do what ever in my while lioo each time the last new latest line get added ..

Comment: I have tested and with even -n1 option  it works fine as it can properly restart my script after one after another